# Alter data type referenced by foreign key in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

We need to change the data type of few tables referenced by foreign key  in MySQL.

Let me explain with an example, Consider **APPOINTMENTS** is a table with a column **APPOINTMENT_ID** and am looking to change the data type of **APPOINTMENT_ID** from Decimal to Double and other requirement is to change the columns having **PRIMARY KEY** should have the **AUTO_INCREMENT**.

How would we do this without effecting my database design.

Comment: Why would you want to have a floating point number as a foreign key (and implying that you use a floating point number as a primary key somewhere)?

Comment: I think you need to show us the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `APPOINTMENTS`.  There is a concern about possible data loss here, so we need to column widths and precisions.

Comment: Those were already defined earlier as we are migrating this database from Oracle to MySQL so we cannot ask them to change their business logic.

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  Double columns can have variable width and precision, and we need to know the precision of the `APPOINTMENT_ID` column to answer your question.

Comment: Oh...if you mean how can you alter a column without using `ALTER TABLE` ... you can't, not AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE <column_name> <column_name> <type> 
    note: you have to write column name twice OR
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY <column_name> <type> ;
```

Like `ALTER TABLE APPOINTMENTS CHANGE APPOINTMENT_ID APPOINTMENT_ID Double`

But Its not a good approach that you make `double` data type for primary key

Comment: I need to change a column from decimal to double and this is another requirement for other table of PRIMARY KEY should have the ‘AUTO_INCREMENT’